# shared object ‘RCurl.so’ not found

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, libcurl, rcurl

#### Data about my system

- R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)   (World-Famous Astronaut)
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

`$ locate RCurl.so`:

```
~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so
~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so
~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so
```

---

`$ r -pie '.libPaths()'`:

```
[1] "~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"           
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                 
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

---

`$ R CMD ldd /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so`:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7734000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0xb7696000)
    libR.so => /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so (0xb7319000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb716f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7151000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0xb711d000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xb710e000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0xb70bc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb70b2000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xb7075000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb705f000)
    libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0xb6f9a000)
    libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0xb6f14000)
    librtmp.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0 (0xb6ef9000)
    libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf (0xb6c24000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6bf8000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0xb6bbe000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb6b82000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xb6b5a000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0xb6b49000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6b44000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0xb6b21000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6b06000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7735000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6aed000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb6ad1000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0xb6a94000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0xb69c5000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xb699d000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0xb6997000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xb698e000)
    libtasn1.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3 (0xb697c000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0xb696a000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb6965000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0xb6856000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb6837000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0xb682f000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0xb67ac000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0xb6707000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0xb66d1000)
    libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0xb66bb000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xb66b7000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0xb6624000)
    libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0xb65fb000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0xb65eb000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0xb65a4000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xb64ff000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb64ce000)
```

(Noted: no `???` error as suggested in [Got message unable to load shared object stats.so when R starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts).)

#### Problem description & what I tried

I apparently have several `RCurl.so` objects, but when I  try to `install.packages('RCurl')` into `~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl/`, I get the following error:

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘RCurl.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/user/1001/RtmpVJ2RYv/downloaded_packages’
```

Running `library.dynam()` with one of the old `RCurl.so`'s didn't work either.

I also tried `R CMD INSTALL [path to downloaded omega-hat source].tar.gz`. Same error.

#### Question

Looking around on the internet there seem to be a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts) [of](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/libR-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-td4675305.html) [people](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/shared-object-libintl-so-9-not-found.49320/) with shared object problems. But I can't tell from those who answered them, what I need to do, or even what help files I need to be reading. I think I've worked through most / every one of the arguments in `?install.packages` and `?INSTALL`.

What else could be going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is always Ubuntu  :)

Comment: @RichardScriven Great! The operating system I chose specifically so it would be the easiest.

Comment: You do have `libcurl4-openssl-dev` installed, right? I had some similar problems (even after installing the above) and the only "fix" I could find was to install `RCurl` from R **run as root**, then go into normal (user) R and install RCurl again. I don't think this is how the problem should be fixed though.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Yep, a reasonable thing to check but this shows up in most of the Google-able help, so in this case I wasn't wrong on that. Thanks though.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I think I did a similar "fix", although I'm still not sure if it's working (I'm way too lost at this point to know what I did, what worked, what failed, or what's still not working.) And I agree, `sudo` seems to be frowned upon as a common way for users to kick themselves in the rear.

Comment: I think https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Configuration-options might be where I need to look......