# Installing RIO Package : shared object ‘haven.so’ not found

Tags: r, installation, package, r-haven, r-rio

I've some problem to install package in R.

I write :

```
install.packages("rio", dependencies = TRUE)
```

And it gives the error message:

> - installing *source* package ‘rio’ ...
>     ** package ‘rio’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
>     ** R
>     ** inst
>     ** preparing package for lazy loading
>     Warning: S3 methods ‘[.labelled’, ‘[.labelled_spss’, ‘as.data.frame.labelled’, ‘as_factor.data.frame’, ‘as_factor.labelled’, ‘is.na.labelled_spss’, ‘print.labelled’, ‘print.labelled_spss’, ‘type_sum.labelled’, ‘zap_formats.data.frame’, ‘zap_formats.default’, ‘zap_labels.data.frame’, ‘zap_labels.default’, ‘zap_labels.labelled’, ‘zap_labels.labelled_spss’, ‘zap_missing.data.frame’, ‘zap_missing.default’, ‘zap_missing.labelled’, ‘zap_missing.labelled_spss’, ‘zap_widths.data.frame’, ‘zap_widths.default’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
>     Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
>     shared object ‘haven.so’ not found
>     ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rio’
>
>   - removing ‘/home/durand-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rio’
>       Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpZI89tI/downloaded_packages/rio_0.4.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I think that I miss some lib-dev or something like that but I cant find which one I need for `rio`'s.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install the `rio` package in Microsoft windows. I faced an error. In order to resolve that issue, I googled and came to this page.

I know this post is a bit old but thought to share it for those who face a similar issue in installing this package.

Similar to this post:
[Error: "there is no package called ..." and trying to use install.packages to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395807/error-there-is-no-package-called-and-trying-to-use-install-packages-to-so)

I could only install `rio` when I used the command:
`install.packages('rio', dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a Linux-specific problem ([Got message unable to load shared object stats.so when R starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts), [shared object ‘RCurl.so’ not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528194/shared-object-rcurl-so-not-found))

Does uninstalling and reinstalling the `haven`package fix it?