# Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) when using ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting this error upon running the following code and do not know how to fix it.  I have `svglite` installed but when I run `library(svglite)` I get the same error:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so
>     Reason: image not found

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(1,2,3,4)

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x=x,y=y), aes(x = x, y = y))  + 
geom_line() + 


ggsave(filename = "ROC_plot_6x4.svg", plot = p, device = "svg", 
   width = 6, height = 4, units = "in")

library(svglite)
```

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts)?

Comment: The *cairo* library is a system requirement for the `gdtools` package. Do you have it installed, e.g. via homebrew?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I really know nothing of homebrew.  I just tried installing it and nothing happened when I typed /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install) into the terminal as directed.  I'm on a mac OS10.12.6, btw.  It appears I don't have that library in my version of R 3.5.  I looked at the link Roman left and did not find it helpful.

Comment: Scratch that, I actually went to Roman's link again and managed to put about 10 folders in the proper library by hand and the problem is solved.  Sorry, Roman, you were correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Fix: Install XQuartz

I ran into this trying to use the library **ggiraph**, which has a **gdtools** dependency. The Mac OS X binaries for both **gdtools** and **systemfonts** (one of its dependencies) have hardcoded links to X11, which corresponds to a default XQuartz installation. So, if you don't have any of these libraries and/or just want to be able to download the binaries with no fuss, then [install XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/).

FWIW, [CRAN's download page for R (OS X)](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) does mention that some packages require X11:

> **Note**: the use of X11 (including `tcltk`) requires XQuartz to be installed since it is no longer part of OS X. Always re-install XQuartz when upgrading your macOS to a new major version.