# Why I get unable to load an R package error after a while?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have installed a package in our server already and was working properly. 
After a few hourse, once I wanted to load it again, I'm getting the following error:

```
 library("SPONGE")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘SPONGE’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/adinfo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gRbase/libs/gRbase.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/adinfo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gRbase/libs/gRbase.so)
```

I've also tried to install it again using

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("SPONGE")
```

But I've got again the error that "Installation has zero exit"

Can someone help me with that?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /TL/opt/R-3.4.0/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /TL/opt/R-3.4.0/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0   
>
```

Comment: can you give some more details about your server setup?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333097/got-message-unable-to-load-shared-object-stats-so-when-r-starts

Comment: try reinstalling `gRbase` and its dependencies (section 3 of http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/software/gR/ )? and post results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: @BenBolker, I've reinstalled gRbase and the sessionInfo print is in OP